# Is there a way create a list comprehension function that works for a set number of items, moves onto the next part of the program, then repeats

Tags: python, list-comprehension, chunking

For background this is a brute force password cracking program I made for a class. The issue with my program right now is memory. I am using the product function from itertools. Creating a list as big as mine has shut down every computer I've tried it on. How can I create a function that splits the list into set chunks and gets rid of the old already hashed and checked against possible passwords? I tried to use simple chunking code and couldn't fix the issue.

```
def main():
start1 = time.time()
totalLines = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
correctHashes = readFile()
for numbers in range(1, 9, 1):
    normal = ["".join(item) for item in itertools.product(totalList, repeat=numbers)]
    passwords = [hashlib.md5(object1.encode()).hexdigest() for object1 in normal]
    for number in totalLines:
        for num in range(0, len(passwords)):
            if passwords[num] == correctHashes[number]:
                end = time.time()
                print(normal[num] + "\t" + str(end - start1))
                correctHashes.pop(number)
                del totalLines[-1]
                break
```

Comment: You don't need to make lists out of `normal` and `passwords` at all, as far as I can tell. The whole *point* of `itertools` is to provided memory efficient iterators, if you make lists out of them, that defeats that purpose

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: **You don't need to create that list**. Now, that may solve y our memory problem. Runtime might still be an issue. But there's no *reason* to create that huge list.

Comment: Then how do I call it. I’m new to using this function.

Comment: Can you help me to fix the code then?